# Browsing on Firefox, Yahoo plays auto audio out of nowhere

Tags: firefox, audio, browser

So recently I was trying to get something done on my browser(s) then long story short, I discovered something strange on Firefox while I tried to browse Yahoo. I have my speaker unmuted and I heard some conversations about whatever in English. I tried to reload the page and it still gave me the audio, and it seems like it's not merely some advertisement hiding in somewhere because the conversations were continuous even after several refreshing. I have uBlock Origin on FF so I tried to disable some connections from some domains, and I found that it's from something under yimg.com. I'm too afraid to turn the plugin off entirely to let Yahoo show me the whole page with such intruding experience from the site to see what element might be playing the audio, but maybe someone here would have an idea if that's some kind of malware or just something legit from Yahoo?
Note that I'm not browsing the English version of Yahoo, so it's really strange of it to automatically play some audio in English conversations to me.

Answer (score 0):

It was a hidden stream of Berkshire Hathaway Annual Meeting. LOL
uBlock Origin apparently didn't do its job too well, I didn't see the stream playing but I still get to hear the audio. No wonder I heard someone sounded really like Bernie Sanders speaking. It is cool that it tries to put the stream up on their home page but uBlock Origin finds it intruding for some reason so maybe Yahoo should care more about users' privacy issue to not let me and my plugins being too paranoid about their web applications.